# How to edit the auth in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a registration form that includes username, Phone number and an address in the registration process. How do you edit the auth to add or delete fields for registration and login?

Comment: 1. You make a call to a GET /create for creating the user. 
2. Send the data in a POST /store call, then validate the data
3. Create the user
4. Log-in the user. Show us what have you done to guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, to delete/add fields correctly in Laravel's registration form, you will have to modify three different places:

- Database Migration of users which is placed in /database/migrations/
- User's model which is placed in /app/User.php
- Registration controller which is placed in /app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

  1. You will edit the *database migration* to add/reomve fields from user's table.
  2. You will edit the *fillable* array in user's model and add/remove the fields you need *(Make sure you type the exact name you have written in the migration file.)*
  3. You will have to edit a couple of functions in the *registration controller*:

     - function *validator* to validate the fields you receive from the blade file.
     - function create to add/remove the fields you have added/removed in the previous files.

And you of course add the fields in the blade file so can send them through the form.

Answer (score 0):

1 update users table using migration

2 run migration

3 made changes in registration view

4 made changes in Auth Registration controller. In validation function and in register function.

Answer (score 0):

first open RegisterController class to make some modifications

***pathToYourApp***/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

1- add your extra fields to `validator` method

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'phone' => 'required|numeric',
         // add another extra fields here
    ]);
}
```

2- now make this fields added to create statement by add extra fields to  `create` method

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
             // add another extra fields here
        ]);
    }
```

of course you should add your extra fields to your `user migration` and add input fields in `blade view`